# Appcelerator Titanium - Setting a View or Label max height

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a list with titles coming from data source. The length of the title is unknown and could be one line, two lines and even more... under the title I want to place the name of the author of the post.

I placed the two labels (the title label and the author label inside a View with `layout: 'vertical'` which places the author label under the title label. But still had to somehow limit the number of rows displayed by the title - I want to have maximum 2 rows. So I've set the height of the subject label.

While setting the height of the label does limit the number of rows displayed, it causes another problem - on rows where the title is 2 lines or more everything looks great. but on rows where the title is only one row, there's now space between that row and the author name - and I want to have the author name right under the label (important thing to notice - the author label has a different font size and color than the title).

If it was just plain old html I would just set `max-height` css property - but Titanium doesn't have that kind of property on Views/Labels. Is there a way to have maximum height on a View?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property max-height being supported by Appcelerator for views. But what you can do is, you can listen for the **postlayout** event for the view and once triggered you can get the **rect**, to get the height of the view. Now in here you can do your magic. If the height of the view is greater than some value you want, then you can fix it, else let is remain as is.

Do let us know if it works for you. If not, we can try to come up with some other solution.

Comment: The title label I have is inside a `ListView` control. I have set the `onPostlayout` event on the title label, but I see it's not being called constantly - it's mainly called on scroll of `ListView` - advice?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can use [maxLines](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-property-maxLines) on a Label.

For Views and iOS you could do the following. Set the view's `height:Ti.UI.SIZE` and use `bottom` to set the minimum space between the views bottom and that of its parent. This only works if the parent has a fixed size.

Listening to `post layout` on a ListView won't work since you would have to set this on the ListView but don't have a way to access the `rect` or `size` property of the ListItem views.

Comment: tried iOS solution - didn't work. It just created extra space between the title label and author label

Comment: It only works if I remove `layout: vertical` from the parent view. but then the label isn't placed right under the title

Comment: Don't forget to also set `top`

Answer (score 0):

I've just added the numberOfLines in the iOS SDK: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24071
It's called `maxLines` for Android parity. It really works for Labels inside ListView templates.